# Alfresco, recognize when a workflow is started

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

I use Alfresco Community 5.2 and my need is to perform some work when one of the default Alfresco's workflow is started.

I could override all the workflows definitions, but I wonder if there is a better and quicker way to do that. The perfect would be a behavior which triggers when a workflow is started.

Is there something like that ?
Any other approach is accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Jeff suggestion, and [this tutorial](https://github.com/keensoft/alfresco-user-task-listener), I managed to implement a task creation/completion listener and do my logic inside those blocks, resolving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything similar to a behavior for workflows that I know of, although if your workflows will always have documents attached you could consider binding a behavior to the workflow package type (I don't recall off-hand what that type is--it might just be cm:folder which wouldn't be that useful).

This is kind of a hack suggestion, but you could implement a quartz job that would run every 30 seconds or every minute or so that would use the workflow service to check to see if any new workflows have started since the last check. If so, your code could be notified and passed the workflow ID, process ID, etc.

The straightforward solution is as you suggested in your original post--just modify the out-of-the-box processes with a task listener that fires when the workflow starts.